# General form of a fermionic Hamiltonian in second quantization

Tags: hamiltonian, fermions, quantum-chemistry

I am a new to quantum chemistry. I've been reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.04789.pdf) and it seems like the equation (1) in the paper which is,

$H = \sum_{pq} T_{pq} a_p^\dagger a_q + \sum_p U_pn_p + \sum_{pq} V_{pq} n_p n_q$  (where $a_p^\dagger$ and $a_p$ are fermionic creation and annihilation operators, and $n_i = a_i^\dagger a_i$ is the number operator),

represents a general form of any fermionic Hamiltonian in second quantization.

However, I thought the second quantization of molecular Hamiltonian is expressed in

$H = \sum_{pq}a_p^\dagger a_q + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{pqrs} h_{pqrs}a_p^\dagger a_q^\dagger a_r a_s $.

How does the first Hamiltonian express the second Hamiltonian? I get that the first term in the first Hamiltonian is equal to the first term in the second Hamiltonian. Also, I get that setting $U_p = 0$. However, I'm not sure how to connect the last term in the first Hamiltonian to the last term in the second Hamiltonian. Why does the second term involve $4$ variables whereas the first one (which claims to be the general form) only has $2$ variables?

Comment: I think that the second one is the most general fermionic Hamiltonian for 2 body interactions (of course with an energy scale $T_{pq}$ in the first term); while the first one is just a special case

Comment: @Matteo The first sentence in the paragraph right below equation (2) in the paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.04789.pdf) said "... a special case of this Hamiltonian ... in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.00023.pdf". If you then see equation (2) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.00023.pdf, they actually studied the second equation I wrote in the main question. Hence, according to the sentence, I think the first one is the most general case and the second one is a special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Matteo is right: the two-body term of the second Hamiltonian is more general than the first one. Consider the two-body term
$$h_{pqrs}a_p^+a_r^+a_qa_s
=h_{pqrs}a_p^+\big(\{a_r^+,a_q\}-a_qa_r^+\big)a_s$$
The summations over $p,q,r,s$ are implicit.
Using the anti-commutation relation $\{a_r^+,a_q\}=\delta_{r,q}$, we get
$$\eqalign{
h_{pqrs}a_p^+a_r^+a_qa_s
&=h_{pqrs}a_p^+\big(\delta_{r,q}-a_qa_r^+\big)a_s\cr
&=h_{pqqs}a_p^+a_s-h_{pqrs}a_p^+a_qa_r^+a_s
}$$
Now consider the special case
$${1\over 2}h_{pqrs}=-V_{pr}\delta_{p,q}\delta_{r,s}$$
The two-body Hamiltonian becomes
$${1\over 2}h_{pqrs}a_p^+a_r^+a_qa_s
=-V_{pr}a_p^+a_r+V_{pr}a_p^+a_pa_r^+a_r$$
Plugging $n_p=a_p^+a_p$, we get finally
$${1\over 2}h_{pqrs}a_p^+a_r^+a_qa_s
=-V_{pr}a_p^+a_r+V_{pr}n_pn_r$$
Conclusion: the two-body term of your second Hamiltonian is a special case of the two-body term of your first Hamiltonian.

The most general Hamiltonian with two-body interaction reads
$$H=-t_{pq}a_p^+a_q+{1\over 2} h_{pqrs}a_p^+a_r^+a_qa_s$$
Your second Hamiltonian corresponds to $t_{pq}=-\delta_{p,q}$ and your first Hamiltonian to ${1\over 2}h_{pqrs}=-V_{pr}\delta_{p,q}\delta_{r,s}$ and $T_{pq}+U\delta_{p,q}=-t_{pq}-V_{pq}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, what is the main difference between the two equation in terms of physical systems that each one describes? I know that the second Hamiltonian is a molecular Hamiltonian (by solving a Hatree-Fock equation). What does the first Hamiltonian describe exactly?

Comment: In the first Hamiltonian, $T_{pq}$ is the probability amplitude of an electron to hop from atom $q$ to atom $p$, $U_p$ (usually denoted $\mu_p$) is a chemical potential on atom $p$. The last term accounts for electron interactions (e.g. Coulomb repulsion). I think that the difference with the second Hamiltonian is that it does not account for exchange energy.